# How do I connect Windows 11 and Ubuntu Server through a male-to-male USB cable?

Tags: usb, windows, file-sharing

I have a Windows 11 computer and a Ubuntu Server computer. How do I file transfer between these two with a USB 3 male-to-male cable? Whenever I plug the two computers together the Ubuntu Server spams me with the error "Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?" and the Windows computer gives me nothing.

Comment: You cannot.  The pin layout is not symmetrical. Both ends are trying to transmit on the (single) TX (transmit) wire, listen on the same (single) RX (receive) wire. That's why it looks like a "bad cable"  to Linux (probably looks bad to Windows, too, but Windows doesn't tell you). This sounds  like an XY problem. What is your final goal? Have you considered other connection methods?